# in mongodb having duplicte key error , dose anyone knows how to solve it please?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

[image]

```
DuplicateKeyError(error.get("errmsg"), 11000, error)
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
```

Comment: It could be solvable with more details, what does you model look like ? How did you configure it ? (have you defined things like unique fields, unique text fields, etc ?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of the code.

Comment: Please just copy/paste code/error messages/etc. into a codeblock rather than posting screenshots.